# In Flask is it possible to write route and login_required without decorators?

Tags: python, flask

I am wondering if there is any way to write this code snippet without using decorators in python

```
@app.route('/info')
@login_required
def user_info():
    return jsonify(current_user)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Writing a specific code a different way of everyone else, is rarely a good idea

Comment: Because I'm just learning that they are called decorator functions and am finding it hard to wrap my mind around and doing so I think can help me figure out how they actually work behind the scenes